# Unable to resume activity error in Android app

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So I have a FragmentActivity thats working perfectly as it stands.

```
public class ChallongeEvent extends FragmentActivity {
    private TextView tab_text;
    private String EVENT_ID, URL;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.challonge_act_event);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        tab_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tab_text);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        EVENT_ID = intent.getStringExtra("event_id");
        URL = "https://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments/" + EVENT_ID + ".json";

        String titles[] = new String[] { getString(R.string.details), getString(R.string.players) };
        int numTabs = titles.length;

        EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), titles, numTabs);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        pager.setCurrentItem(numTabs - 1);

        SlidingTabLayout sliding_tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        sliding_tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        sliding_tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        populate();
    }

    private void populate() {
        AsyncGet fetch = new AsyncGet(new AsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(String output) {
                for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments())
                {
                    if (fragment instanceof ChallongePlayers) {
                        ((ChallongePlayers) fragment).parsePlayers(output);
                    } else if (fragment instanceof ChallongeMatches) {
                        ((ChallongeMatches) fragment).parseMatches(output);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(URL).newBuilder();
        urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("api_key", Challonge.API_KEY);
        urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("include_participants", "1");
        urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("include_matches", "1");
        fetch.execute(urlBuilder.build().toString());
    }
}
```

When the FragmentActivity launches, it fetches JSON from an API, then sends the data of this API to several Fragments within the pager. It does this with the following code:

```
        AsyncGet fetch = new AsyncGet(new AsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(String output) {
                for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments())
                {
                    if (fragment instanceof ChallongePlayers) {
                        ((ChallongePlayers) fragment).parsePlayers(output);
                    } else if (fragment instanceof ChallongeMatches) {
                        ((ChallongeMatches) fragment).parseMatches(output);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(URL).newBuilder();
        urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("api_key", Challonge.API_KEY);
        urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("include_participants", "1");
        urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("include_matches", "1");
        fetch.execute(urlBuilder.build().toString());
```

However, each of these Fragments has a `SwipeRefreshLayout` within it, that I would like to activate `.setRefreshing(true)` on before the AsyncTask request. So I made the SwipeRefreshLayout on each of those fragments as public and I tried to add the following above the `AsyncGet fetch = ...` line:

```
        for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments())
        {
            if (fragment instanceof ChallongePlayers) {
                ((ChallongePlayers) fragment).swipe_container.setRefreshing(true);
            } else if (fragment instanceof ChallongeMatches) {
                ((ChallongeMatches) fragment).swipe_container.setRefreshing(true);
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately, the first line of this code produces an error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Is it possible that you have not yet added any Fragments by the time `getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()` is called?

Comment: The fragments are added in `init()`, which happens `onCreate`, the first run of populate can happen in `onResume`, which is after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection returned by the `getFragments()` call has not been initialized yet and is null.

You can add an `if` check to make sure `getFragments()` does not return a `null` collection before iterating over it:

```
if(getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments() != null) {
    for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments())
    {
        if (fragment instanceof ChallongePlayers) {
            ((ChallongePlayers) fragment).swipe_container.setRefreshing(true);
        } else if (fragment instanceof ChallongeMatches) {
            ((ChallongeMatches) fragment).swipe_container.setRefreshing(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();` didn't change anything... but checking for the null was a good enough solution.

Comment: Might as well remove that from the answer then. I guess the `FragmentPagerAdapter` must be doing something a little different with the fragments.